# Firebase save data user related

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I am currently writing an android app. In my app users can rate some objects. The data (the objects as well as the ratings) shall be stored in Google Firebase, especially Firestore.
I already linked my app to Firebase and implemented the `com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin` to get the `GoogleSignInAccount` of the current user.

---

I want to save the data to the database like:

```
SomeObject: | objectId | name |

ObjectRating: | ratingId | objectId | userId | rating |
```

---

What I am not sure about is, what to save as userId. The documentation of `GoogleSignInAccount.getId()` says:

> Important: Do not use this returned Google ID to communicate the currently signed in user to your backend server. Instead, send an ID token (requestIdToken(String)), which can be securely validated on the server; or send a server auth code (requestServerAuthCode(String)) which can be in turn exchanged for id token.

So I probably should not use this. But the recommended `IdToken` is signed, so I think it will be different everytime the method is called.

What most people do, is create a users directory in the database. But from the app I want to get the users rating as well as the overall mean rating of all users for the given object. So I think splitting the ratings in multiple user tables complicates the computation of the overall mean rating.

My question is: How can I link the ObjectRating to the user, without using the unsafe `getId()` while still be able to select all ObjectRatings by objectId to compute the mean rating?

Comment: Why so complicated? Why not using Firebase Auth rather than Google sign in? It even easier if using Firebase-UI

Comment: try to get userId From Firebase Auth.!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To obtain the user's unique identifier you can use [`FirebaseAuth`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth) to get the [`FirebaseUser`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser) object:

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
```

The [`getUid()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser#getUid()) method:

> Returns a string used to uniquely identify your user in your Firebase
>   project's user database. Use it when storing information in Firebase
>   Database or Storage, or even in your own backend.

You'll need to ensure that you've [used the `GoogleSignInAccount` to authenticate with Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin) before calling `getCurrentUser()`, otherwise it will return `null`.